# Passing DataFrame from notebook to another with pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

i'am trying to call a DataFrame that i created in notebook1 to use it in my notebook2 in Databricks Community addition with pyspark and i tried this code  `dbutils.notebook.run("notebook1", 60, {"dfnumber2"})`
but it shows this error.
py4j.Py4JException: Method _run([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.util.HashSet, null, class java.lang.String]) does not exist

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that you pass last parameter (`{"dfnumber2"}`) incorrectly - with this syntax it's a `set`, not the `map` type. You need to use syntax: `{"table_name": "dfnumber2"}` to represent it as a dict/map.

But if you look into [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html) of dbutils.notebook.run, you will see following phrase:

> To implement notebook workflows, use the `dbutils.notebook.*` methods. Unlike `%run`, the `dbutils.notebook.run()` method **starts a new job** to run the notebook.

But jobs aren't supported on the Community Edition, so it won't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global temp view and pass the table name as argument to your next notebook.

Drnumber2.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("dfnumber2")

dbutils.notebook.run("notebook1", 60, {table_name:"dfnumber2"})

In your notebook1 you can do

table_name= dbutils.widgets.get("table_name")
Dfnumber2 = spark.sql("select * from global_temp."+table_name)